# Apple Swift: Initialize Array of Generic Type

Tags: arrays, generics, swift

I have an array (member of a class) of generic type T. The generic type will only be numeric types (double, int, etc). My question is how to initialize this array to all the same number in the initializer?

I've seen this:

```
self.data = Double[](count: 3, repeatedValue: 1.0)
```

So I tried this but it doesn't work...

```
self.data = T[](count: 3, repeatedValue: 1.0)
```

Anybody know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Swift doesn't do implicit casting; have you tried `repeatedValue: T(1)`, and an appropriate type constraint on `T`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, here's what I just did:

```
protocol Initable {
    init()
}

class Bar:<T: Initable> {
    var     ar: T[]

    init(length: Int) {
        self.ar = T[](count:length, repeatedValue: T())
    }
}
```

Then you just have to make sure that any `T` that you use implements the `Initable` protocol, e.g.:

```
extension Int:Initable {}
```

which lets me do this:

```
var foo = Bar<Int>(3)
```

I also used a prototyping alternative:

```
class Bar:<T> {
    var     ar: T[]

    init(length: Int, proto:T) {
        self.ar = T[](count:length, repeatedValue:proto)
    }
}
```

which doesn't require the protocol, but does need a supplied initial value:

```
var foo = Bar<Int>(length: 3, proto: 34)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used what you called the "prototyping alternative". It actually worked just fine for what I needed.

Comment: From my reading of the documentation, the problem with the prototyping implementation is that if the type `T` is a class, it will be passed by reference, which would mean that your array would be filled with a list of references to a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it will not limit the data types to be only numeric types:

```
self.data = AnyObject[](count: 3, repeatedValue: 1.0)
```